# How to get JS field value and use it in Controller Code behind MVC4 / JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using ASP.Net MVC4 , with Jquery UI date picker to deal with date field 
I wonder to know how can I use the variables in the code .

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });

        $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<p>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="date" id="from" name="from" value='<%=from%>'/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="date" id="to" name="to" value='<%=to%>'/>
</p>
```

I would like to use the values that I ve gotten from "from"/"to" field and work with them in my Controller .

```
  public ActionResult index( )
        {
            DateTime first = 

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: no such concept of "code-behind" in mvc. purge it from your brain ... :) there's server and client and this thing in the middle called http ...

Comment: So , what should I do ! How Can I retrieve a fields' values !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="date" id="from" name="from" value='<%=from%>'/>
        <label for="to">to</label>
        <input type="date" id="to" name="to" value='<%=to%>'/>
    </p>    
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and a controller action that will be invoked and passed as parameters the fields:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    // when the form is submitted this action will be invoked and passed the 
    // selected values
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**From:**

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="date" id="from" name="from" value='<%=from%>'/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="date" id="to" name="to" value='<%=to%>'/>
```

**To:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)){
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="date" id="from" name="from" value='<%=from%>'/>
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="date" id="to" name="to" value='<%=to%>'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
}
```

Comment: Seems that this is the right thing ! but in the server side I couldn t get the value  "DateTime first = from ;"

Comment: I wonder to know how can I get the values , Should I make it in the entrance   public ActionResult index(Date from , date to )
        {
            DateTime first = 

            return View();
        }